# In Android how to set multiple(2 or 3) checkboxes text should be displayed on next page?

Tags: android

In an activity we have 3 or 4 multiple Checkboxes and two buttons one for submitting data other for clearing the selected checkboxes.
On clicking the selected checkboxes data should be displayed on next page, can anyone provide a solution how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Demo Calss Call Second Class.
```

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private Button btnSubmit, btnClear;
    private CheckBox chk1, chk2, chk3;
    private Bundle data = new Bundle();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        chk1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk1);
        chk2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk2);
        chk3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk3);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

        chk1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        chk2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        chk3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSubmit:
            Intent intent = new Intent(DemoActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(data);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.btnClear:
            chk1.setChecked(false);
            chk2.setChecked(false);
            chk3.setChecked(false);
            break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.chk1:
            if (isChecked) {
                data.putString("Value1", chk1.getText().toString());
                Log.v("chk1", chk1.getText().toString());
            } else {
                if (data.containsKey("Value1")) {
                    data.remove("Value1");
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.chk2:
            if (isChecked) {
                data.putString("Value2", chk2.getText().toString());
                Log.v("chk2", chk2.getText().toString());
            } else {
                if (data.containsKey("Value2")) {
                    data.remove("Value2");
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.chk3:
            if (isChecked) {
                data.putString("Value3", chk3.getText().toString());
                Log.v("chk3", chk3.getText().toString());
            } else {
                if (data.containsKey("Value3")) {
                    data.remove("Value3");
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}


public class secondActivity extends Activity {

    private Bundle data;
    private TextView txtView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String Value = "";
        data = intent.getExtras();
        if (data.containsKey("Value1")) {
            Value = data.getString("Value1");
            Log.v("Value", Value);
            txtView.setText(Value);
        }
        if (data.containsKey("Value2")) {
            Value += data.getString("Value2");
            Log.v("Value", Value);
            txtView.setText(Value);
        }
        if (data.containsKey("Value3")) {
            Value += data.getString("Value3");
            Log.v("Value", Value);
            txtView.setText(Value);
        }
    }

}
```

//main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Red" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blue" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Green" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

//second xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```